# St. John's greatest dinner: how to indicate a possessive of a noun which already ends apostrophe - s

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, double-possessive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If the cricket ground Lord's is a possessive, what if you want to describe something belonging to Lord's?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/if-the-cricket-ground-lords-is-a-possessive-what-if-you-want-to-describe-someth)

Here's a tricky one that I can't quite figure out the correct punctuation for.  How do you write the possessive of a noun which is already possessive?  The example which spawned this question:

How would you describe something belonging to St. John's, where St. John's is any of the colleges, towns or hospitals which bear this name, including the apostrophe, and not the saint?

*edit*

@waiwai933: This is what I've always done, I just wondered if there was any clever punctuation you could use to avoid this kind of rephrasing.  I'm guessing from your immediate reply that the answer is probably no, but I'll see if anyone else comes up with something interesting.

Comment: You could write St. John's' - although it does look odd. I don't know if it is valid anymore, but it certainly isn't common (but if you read some Victorian-era books, you would see that kind of usage, as well as words like "is'n't" and "has'n't").

Comment: Duplicate of [If the cricket ground Lord's is a possessive, what if you want to describe something belonging to Lord's?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/if-the-cricket-ground-lords-is-a-possessive-what-if-you-want-to-describe-someth)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - agreed, I didn't find that on my initial search.  How do I merge in, or do I need an admin for that?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid ambiguity and use the full name if possible.

> St. John's College's admissions office
>
> St. John's Hospital's triage area

If not, rephrase.

> The schoolhouse of St. John's, Redhill
>
> ---
>
> @waiwai933: This is what I've always
>   done, I just wondered if there was any
>   clever punctuation you could use to
>   avoid this kind of rephrasing. I'm
>   guessing from your immediate reply
>   that the answer is probably no, but
>   I'll see if anyone else comes up with
>   something interesting.

That's correct. There's no real way around it, unless you've referred to it already, in which case you could step around mentioning the name altogether:

> Its new surgical ward has just opened.

Comment: I agree; I have never seen _St. John's's_ (or _St. John's'_) being used.

Comment: Eh… this seems like answering “James’ or James’s?” by “Neither, you should always use his surname!”  If there’s a St John’s College (Hospital, etc.) that you and your friends talk about frequently, then there’s no way you’ll end up naming it in full every time in speech, and no good reason to do so in writing.  Also, one could be talking about eg the city of St. John’s, in Newfoundland, where there’s no noun to evade the question with…

Comment: @PLL The fact is, there is no other way to do this. And we're only addressing the possessive case here—it's fine to say "St John's just opened a new ward", but not "St. John's'(s) new ward". Assuming you've already referred to it, you could say "its new ward". And as to the city case, the name of a city is a proper noun.

Comment: @waiwai933 -- it's too bad we don't sat "St. John's's".  Then we could say, "St. John's's new ward's walls are painted blue, but St. James's's's are white."  (Exercise for the reader: a plausible sentence with _four_ 's-es.)