# How to Pluralize a Proper Noun That Already Has a "'s" In It

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe

How does one pluralize a proper noun that already has an apostrophe in its singular form?

- for example, McDonalds'...  How would I say there are three McDondald's in California?

Please note: I am ***not*** asking how to write a ***possessive*** form for a proper noun that already has a 's in it, I am asking how to ***pluralize*** a proper noun that already has a 's in it.

(The first instance has already been answered previously, and used McDonald's for an example as well)

Thank you!

Comment: English is so awesome that I sometimes forget how weird it is. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: That is interesting. Is there a formal way of writing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is very similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12505/st-johns-greatest-dinner-how-to-indicate-a-possessive-of-a-noun-which-already?rq=1), but, as you note, not a true duplicate, because you're asking how to pluralize an already-possessive noun, rather than how to make it possessive.

However, many of the same tricks involved still apply.  Namely, it's really best avoid the issue by rephrasing it in a manner which allows you to pluralize a different word instead, such as:

> There are three McDonald's locations in California

Comment: Ah, okay! I see what you did. What if I had no choice? ....Or is there no clear cut answer for this?

Comment: I can't come up with any situation in which there's no choice, but in that case, I'd probably stick with **'s** and not worry about it too much.