# Possessive of Queen's?

Tags: nouns, possessives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possessive of a word that's already possessive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/possessive-of-a-word-thats-already-possessive)

I ran into this issue today. Referring to Queen's University, how would you say "I've been accepted to Queen's MA program?"

Would you move the apostrophe over to make it Queens'?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/if-the-cricket-ground-lords-is-a-possessive-what-if-you-want-to-describe-someth).

Comment: My apologies, I tried a search for similar questions but I wasn't sure how to phrase my query to get the results I want.

Comment: That's okay.  No big deal :)

Comment: It would have been *so* much easier if you'd gone the engineering route -- "I've been dyed purple" is quite a bit less grammatically complicated.

Comment: I've edited the older question's title to make it more generic, and thus hopefully easier to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we would wind up with "Queen's's", which is just not happening, so I would studiously avoid the issue by saying "I've been accepted to Queen's University's MA program" or "I've been accepted to the MA program at Queen's".

Comment: Sidestepping is definitely the way to go.  Another possible alternative is "I've been accepted to the Queen's University MA program".

Comment: It seems that workarounds are the only way to deal with this. Thanks all.