# What is the best use of the apostrophe in a church name when the church also "possesses" something?

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possessive of a word that’s already possessive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/possessive-of-a-word-thats-already-possessive)

For example, would it be correct to write St. Marys' basketball team for the basketball team belonging to St. Mary's church?

Comment: It's not the team of *St. Mary's*, so you don't need the extra apostrophe there. It's *St. Mary's **church's*** team, but as with [St. John's](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22st+john's+team%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), the easiest way around the issue is to just refer to it as ***the** St. Mary's team* (think of *St. Mary's* as a noun serving in an adjectival capacity).

Comment: Yes, "adjectival capacity" is a good way of putting it. Thanks! (It does make one wonder about [St. James' Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_James'_Park)...)

Comment: @Michelle: why does it make you wonder that? The S in James is part of the name. The S in Mary, on the other hand — wait, *there is no S in Mary*. It's St. Mary's, but it's not St. Jame's.

Answer (score 2):

In Ireland, a parish might have the name "St. Michael's parish". However, their GAA club would be called St. Michael's GAA club.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Michael%27s_GAA

So, I would consider St. Mary's Basketball Team to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Any difficulty can be removed by writing *St Marys basketball team* or *St Marys Church basketball team*. Affiliative use seems to be one area where the apostrophe is disappearing, and no bad thing either.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the second possessive indicator and it **can** be dispensed with. It is not always necessary to show the ownership explicitly in cases such as this. *St. Mary's* can also be used in an adjectival sense to modify 'basketball team'.

*St. Mary* →
*St. Mary's Church* (can be also referred to as *St. Mary's*) →
*St. Mary's Basketball Team*
Note the capitalization as you are referring to a particular named team.

"[USA Baseball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA_Baseball) organizes various teams composed of High School, College, and Professional baseball players competing nationally and internationally."

The *England Football Team* makes as much sense as the *England's football team* and better sense than the *English football team* (could be ambiguous, in fact).