# How to use possessive form for proper nouns that already have an apostrophe

Tags: possessives

How would one write a possessive form for a proper noun that already has an apostrophe-s in it? For example, I want to use the possessive form of "McDonald's" maybe in the sentence "The Market Street McDonald's' employees are friendly."

I realize the possessive form may not be entirely necessary there, but in a case where it is, what is correct?

Comment: Even worse is the possessive of the plural of proper nouns that have an apostrophe in their singular form. E.g.: "In this town the McDonald'ses' hours are worse than the Wendy'ses'."

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. They are two distinct but related questions. A singular proper noun ending with *'s,* such as *McDonald's,* is different from a proper noun ending in the plural suffix *s,* such as *Dunkin' Donuts.*

Comment: It's true the first sentence of this question just says "already has an s in it," but the title mentions apostrophes, so the question as  a whole is more specific. I think it would be more appropriate to mark it as a duplicate of the following question: [Possessive of a word that is already possessive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/possessive-of-a-word-that-is-already-possessive)

Comment: My bad, if you look closely, I include the apostrophe in the double quotes to mean "already has an apostrophe-s in it" but I should change it since it's hard to read

Answer (score 5):

Technically it could be *McDonald's'* or *McDonald's's* because "McDonald's" functions as a singular noun. However, most style guides (and common sense, IMO) suggest you avoid it altogether by rephrasing the sentence:

> The Market Street McDonald's has friendly employees.
>
> The employees at Market Street McDonald's are friendly.

*McDonald's* happens to be a common example used to illustrate it:

[Excerpt from The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style](http://books.google.com/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA262&lpg=PA262&dq=mcdonald%27s%20possessive&source=bl&ots=6GiR8k5XI1&sig=p7I2CqTiIv_8-wX-aeS0cMwE2bQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UYBqU8eOHNLesASwo4G4BQ&ved=0CFAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=mcdonald%27s%20possessive&f=false)

[Grammarphobia blog post](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2007/03/how-possessive-can-you-get.html)

[Another example on quickanddirtytips.com](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-make-names-apostrophes-possessive)