# Possessive of company name already ending in 's

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

If one were speaking of, say, something belonging to the company named Denny's, would the correct punctuation be Denny's'? Thanks!

Comment: I did read all of these.  I guess I'm looking for a definitive answer - maybe there isn't one? - and these seem to be opinions.  I can't change the wording at all, as it's testimony I'm transcribing, so it has to stay exactly as is.

Comment: Isn't [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2936/240807) definite? **If "Lord's" already *is* a possessive, then there's no need to turn it into a possessive even further.**

Comment: I guess I don't feel like it is.  I need a "rule."  To me, "Lord's" looks like it's something possessed by "Lord," not "Lord's Department Store" or whatever. JMO. I'm going with Lord's', weird as it looks.

Comment: [Lord's Cricket Ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s) was founded by Thomas Lord - names like this _are_ simply the possessive form. I doubt very much that an apostrophe either side of the 's' is correct.

Comment: Beyond what's already been said, you could consult an individual business to see if they have a style guide or preference. But there is no general rule for all English-language business names.

Comment: [Here's](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0eEWAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA58&ots=PS4-6Amv5K&dq=what%20is%20possessive%20of%20Denny's&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q=what%20is%20possessive%20of%20Denny's&f=false) a Business English book that says "Denny's alcoholic beverage" is correct, i.e. "Denny's" is the possessive, if you want a rule from someone who has nominated themselves as an authority.

Comment: Well, for some reason I can't post "thank you."  Ah.  Maybe two words is simply too short.  Haha.  But thank you.